# Angular JS send parameter and return result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem. I want to call a function with arguments and to get results by `ng-click` on `.md-button`.

In HTML

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="setreg.register({{reg.email}},{{reg.pass1}},{{reg.pass2}},{{reg.name}});" style="width: 100%">
                Kayıt Ol
            </md-button>
            <div>
                <label>Result :</label>{{setreg.SetRegister}}
            </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngMaterial", "ngMessages"]);

app.controller("SetRegister", ["$http", function ($http) {
var result = this;
var dbName = "0";
var dbUserName = "0";
var dbPassword = "0";
var dbUrl = "0";


var register = function (email, pass1, pass2, name) {
    if (pass1 !== pass2) {
        result.SetRegister = "[{\"result\":\"Şifre doğrulaması yapılamadı\"}]";
    } else {
        var query = "INSERT INTO users (FullName,email,Pass) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + pass1 + "')";
        var url = "http://37.247.113.31:20083/Services/SetData.aspx?dbUrl=" + dbUrl + "&dbUName=" + dbUserName + "&dbPass=" + dbPassword + "&dbDbName=" + dbName + "&query=" + query;
        $http.get(url).success(function (data) { result.SetRegister = data; });
        $http.get(url).error(alert("ERROR"));
    }
};
result.SetRegister = register;
}]);
```

What is wrong? And how can I implement it?
Best regards

Comment: Why are you using `$http.get(url)` twice?

Comment: try `ng-click="setreg.register(reg.email,reg.pass1,reg.pass2,reg.name);"`

Comment: I'm sending a query parameter in the URL you have a database with information returns results as json me my room.
For example: http: xx.com/services/setdata.aspx? .......... INSERT INTO CC (Y) VALUES ('AAA)
the result is [{"result": "OK"}] or [{"result": "FAIL - ex message"}]

I've been using this method for testing the operation of the.

Comment: You do not need multiple AJAX calls, simply chain them. so `$http.get.success().error()`. Then you only make a single AJAX call. Also you do not need the `{{}}` in your `ng-click` as 'Vineet' said because this is already an angular expression and as such will be parsed by the directive. They are needed when binding straight into the view, raw HTML or normal attributes etc or when a directive doesn't expect an expression.

Answer (score 0):

im solved this. 
Thanks all answered.

JS

```
app.controller("SetRegister", ["$http", function ($http) {
var result = this;
var dbName = "0";
var dbUserName = "0";
var dbPassword = "0";
var dbUrl = "0";


var register = function (email, pass1, pass2, name) {
    if (pass1 !== pass2) {
        result.SetRegister = "[{\"result\":\"Şifre doğrulaması yapılamadı\"}]";
    } else {
        var query = "INSERT INTO users (FullName,email,Pass) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + pass1 + "')";
        var url = "http://37.247.113.31:20083/Services/SetData.aspx?dbUrl=" + dbUrl + "&dbUName=" + dbUserName + "&dbPass=" + dbPassword + "&dbDbName=" + dbName + "&query=" + query;
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) { result.SetRegister = data; });
        $http.get(url).error(function (data) { result.SetRegister = data; });
    }
};
result.SetRegister = register;
```

}]);

HTML

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="setreg.SetRegister(reg.email,reg.pass1,reg.pass2,reg.name);" style="width: 100%">
```

this send request quesry and response ok OR FAIL eex message. service is ınsert data in db.